# How would I implement render scaling in a DX11 game?

Tags: directx11

I would like to implement render scaling that could render a scene at a certain % of the window resolution. How would I do this? I've tried resizing a number of things, then resizing them up or down to match the window size but I've never gotten it to work.

Comment: With DirectX 11.1 or later (Windows 7 SP1 with KB 2670838 or Windows 8+) you can use ``DXGI_SCALING_STRETCH`` and set your backbuffer to a smaller size than the actual window/display you are using. With UWP or Windows 10 DX12, you can use ``DXGI_SCALING_ASPECT_RATIO_STRETCH`` which gives you better behavior that preserves the aspect-ratio of the backbuffer when doing the upscale.

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious one and probably most hacky is to:

1 - Create your rendertarget at the % of the screen size (MSAA or NON MSAA)

2 - Create a transition Rendertarget at the windowsize (NON MSAA)  I advise NON MSAA as you then don't have to use the more expensive ResolveSubResource call.

3 - Upon completion of your rendering to your rendertarget, use this as a source texture for your rendering to a fullscreen quad into your NON MSAA transition target.

4 - Copy the resource into your swap buffer.

You could do a fullscreen quad straight to the swap buffer, but I cant remember if that means you can not utilise SWAP_SEQUENTIAL or SWAP_DISCARD.